# Data not rendering in Line chart made up of highcharts custom Line component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, typescript, highcharts

I am newbie to Highcharts. I want to achieve the 2 charts like this [image]charts[image]

For this I have created a custom line chart component with highcharts to replace the existing library. The component I created contains the interface as

```
export interface LineChartProps {
  title?: string;
  xTitle?: string;
  yTitle?: string;
  chartWidth?: number;
  chartHeight?: number;
  seriesData: any[][];
  seriesColor: string[];
  gridLine?:boolean;
  name?: any;
}
```

and the previous code before the modification was

```
    private getAlertTrendGraph = (alertTrendData: TrendType) => {
        /* Reading in the Alert Trend API Data and constructing the Chart Lines. */
        let result = ['Low', 'Medium', 'High'].map((keyValue, index) => {
            if (alertTrendData.values[keyValue] !== undefined) {

                let alertTrendValue = alertTrendData.values[keyValue].map((data) => {
                    return (parseInt(data, 10));
                });
                let color = '#FFFFFF';
                if (keyValue === 'Low') {
                    color = '#27AEF0';
                }
                else if (keyValue === 'Medium') {
                    color = '#FFC627';
                }
                else if (keyValue === 'High') {
                    color = '#ED3124';
                }
                return (
                    <Chart.Line
                        key={'AlertTrend' + index}
                        name={keyValue}
                        data={alertTrendValue}
                        color={color}
                    />
                );
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
        return result;

    }

    private complianceTrendGraph = (complianceTrendData: TrendType) => {
        /* Reading in the Compliance Trend API Data and constructing the Chart Lines. */
        let result = complianceTrendData.keys.map((keyValue, index) => {
            let complianceTrendValue = complianceTrendData.values[keyValue].map((data) => {
                return (parseFloat(data));
            });
            return (
                <Chart.Line
                    key={'ComplianceTrend' + index}
                    name={keyValue}
                    data={complianceTrendValue}
                />
            );
        });
        return result;
    }

    convertUTCToLocalDate(timestamps:Array<string>){
        let localTimestamps:any=[];
        timestamps.map((dateTime)=>{
        const sp=dateTime.toString().split(" ");
        if(sp[0]! && sp[1]!){
        const date = new Date(sp[0]);
        const month =((date.getMonth()+1)<10)?"0"+(date.getMonth()+1):(date.getMonth()+1);
        const day =(date.getDate()<10)?"0"+date.getDate():date.getDate();
        let str1=date.getFullYear()+'-' + month+'-'+day+'T'+sp[1];
        let ISOdate=new Date(str1+'Z');
        const utc=moment.utc(ISOdate);
        const local=utc.local();
        localTimestamps.push(local.format('DD MMM YYYY').toString());
    }
  });
  return localTimestamps;
}  

    onTabChange = (index: number) => {
        const store = this.props.dashboardStore!;
        if(index === 1 && !this.alertTrendGraph[0]) {
            store.updateLoaderCount();
            store.postDataQuery('AlertTrend', this.category, this.data,'');
        }
    }    

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.alertTrendGraph = undefined;
    }

    render() {
        const store = this.props.dashboardStore!;
        let alertTrendData = toJS(store.alertTrend!);
        let complianceTrendData = toJS(store.complianceTrend!);
        if (alertTrendData.keys === undefined || complianceTrendData.keys === undefined) {
            return (
                <div />
            );
        } else {
            alertTrendData.timestamps = this.convertUTCToLocalDate(alertTrendData.timestamps);
            complianceTrendData.timestamps = this.convertUTCToLocalDate(complianceTrendData.timestamps);
            this.alertTrendGraph = this.getAlertTrendGraph(alertTrendData);
            let complianceTrendGraph = this.complianceTrendGraph(complianceTrendData);

            return (
                <div className="systemview-graph">
                    <Tab defaultActiveIndex={0} onTabChange={(activeIndex)=>(this.onTabChange(activeIndex))} >
                        <Tab.Pane title="Score Trend">
                            <Chart animation={false} height="350" key="Chart2">
                                {complianceTrendGraph}
                                <Chart.YAxis
                                    showGridLines={true}
                                    gridLineColor="#202020"
                                    labels={{ enabled: false }}
                                    tickLength={5}
                                    tickWidth={1}
                                    lineWidth={1}
                                    lineColor="white"
                                    min={0.0}
                                    max={100.0}
                                    title={{text: "Percent(%)", style: { color: 'white', fontSize: '15px' } }}
                                />
                                <Chart.XAxis
                                    showGridLines={false}
                                    labels={{ style: { color: 'white', fontSize: '15px' } }}
                                    tickLength={10}
                                    tickWidth={1}
                                    tickColor="white"
                                    categories={complianceTrendData.timestamps}

                                />
                                <Chart.Legend
                                    align="left"
                                    verticalAlign="bottom"
                                />
                            </Chart>
                        </Tab.Pane>
                        <Tab.Pane title="Alert Trend">
                            <Chart animation={false} height="350" key="Chart1">
                                {this.alertTrendGraph}
                                <Chart.YAxis
                                    showGridLines={true}
                                    gridLineColor="#202020"
                                    labels={{ enabled: false }}
                                    tickLength={5}
                                    tickWidth={1}
                                    lineWidth={1}
                                    lineColor="white"
                                />

                                <Chart.XAxis
                                    showGridLines={false}
                                    labels={{ style: { color: 'white', fontSize: '15px' } }}
                                    tickLength={10}
                                    tickWidth={1}
                                    tickColor="white"
                                    categories={alertTrendData.timestamps}
                                />
                                <Chart.Legend
                                    align="left"
                                    verticalAlign="bottom"
                                />
                            </Chart>
                        </Tab.Pane>

                    </Tab>
                </div>
            );
        }
```

Now the modified code is

```
    private getAlertTrendGraph = (alertTrendData: TrendType) => {
        /* Reading in the Alert Trend API Data and constructing the Chart Lines. */
        let result = ['Low', 'Medium', 'High'].map((keyValue, index) => {
            if (alertTrendData.values[keyValue] !== undefined) {

                let alertTrendValue = alertTrendData.values[keyValue].map((data) => {
                    return (parseInt(data, 10));
                });
                let color = '#FFFFFF';
                if (keyValue === 'Low') {
                    color = '#27AEF0';
                }
                else if (keyValue === 'Medium') {
                    color = '#FFC627';
                }
                else if (keyValue === 'High') {
                    color = '#ED3124';
                }
                return (
                    <LineChart
                        key={'AlertTrend' + index}
                        name={keyValue}
                        seriesData={[alertTrendValue]}
                        seriesColor={[color]} 
                        />
                );
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
        return result;

    }

    private complianceTrendGraph = (complianceTrendData: TrendType) => {
        /* Reading in the Compliance Trend API Data and constructing the Chart Lines. */
        let result = complianceTrendData.keys.map((keyValue, index) => {
            let complianceTrendValue = complianceTrendData.values[keyValue].map((data) => {
                return (parseFloat(data));
            });
            return (
                <LineChart
                    key={'ComplianceTrend' + index}
                    name={keyValue}
                    seriesData={[complianceTrendValue]} 
                    seriesColor={['#FFFFFF']}                
                />
            );
        });
        return result;
    }

    convertUTCToLocalDate(timestamps:Array<string>){
        let localTimestamps:any=[];
        timestamps.map((dateTime)=>{
        const sp=dateTime.toString().split(" ");
        if(sp[0]! && sp[1]!){
        const date = new Date(sp[0]);
        const month =((date.getMonth()+1)<10)?"0"+(date.getMonth()+1):(date.getMonth()+1);
        const day =(date.getDate()<10)?"0"+date.getDate():date.getDate();
        let str1=date.getFullYear()+'-' + month+'-'+day+'T'+sp[1];
        let ISOdate=new Date(str1+'Z');
        const utc=moment.utc(ISOdate);
        const local=utc.local();
        localTimestamps.push(local.format('DD MMM YYYY').toString());
    }
  });
  return localTimestamps;
}  

    onTabChange = (index: number) => {
        const store = this.props.dashboardStore!;
        if(index === 1 && !this.alertTrendGraph[0]) {
            store.updateLoaderCount();
            store.postDataQuery('AlertTrend', this.category, this.data,'');
        }
    }    

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.alertTrendGraph = undefined;
    }

    render() {
        const store = this.props.dashboardStore!;
        let alertTrendData = toJS(store.alertTrend!);
        let complianceTrendData = toJS(store.complianceTrend!);
        if (alertTrendData.keys === undefined || complianceTrendData.keys === undefined) {
            return (
                <div />
            );
        } else {
            alertTrendData.timestamps = this.convertUTCToLocalDate(alertTrendData.timestamps);
            complianceTrendData.timestamps = this.convertUTCToLocalDate(complianceTrendData.timestamps);
            this.alertTrendGraph = this.getAlertTrendGraph(alertTrendData);
            let complianceTrendGraph = this.complianceTrendGraph(complianceTrendData);

            return (
                <div className="systemview-graph">
                    <Tab defaultActiveIndex={0} onTabChange={(activeIndex)=>(this.onTabChange(activeIndex))} >
                        <Tab.Pane title="Score Trend">
                                <LineChart 
                                seriesData={[complianceTrendGraph]} 
                                seriesColor={['#1792E5']} />
                              
                        </Tab.Pane>
                        <Tab.Pane title="Alert Trend">
                            <LineChart 
                            seriesData={[this.alertTrendGraph]} 
                            seriesColor={['#1792E5']} />
                        </Tab.Pane>

                    </Tab>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to achieve the exact charts. Can someone please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I recommend you to use the officially supported wrapper for Highcharts in React: [highcharts-react-official](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official)

The wrapper supports many common use cases out-of-the-box and it is really easy to create the required chart with it. Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-nskz3y

---

However, in your case, you need to render only one `LineChart` component with multiple series, not multiple `LineChart` components with one series.

```
  const renderChart = () => {
    const seriesData = [];

    ["Low", "Medium", "High"].forEach((keyValue) => {
      const alertTrendValue = alertTrendData.values[keyValue].map((data) => {
        return parseInt(data, 10);
      });

      seriesData.push({
        color,
        data: alertTrendValue,
        type: "spline"
      });
    });
    return <LineChart seriesData={seriesData} />;
  };
```

---

**Live example:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-dem-nskz3y

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line